# How to find number of terms in a geometric progression

Tags: geometric-progressions

What is the equation two find the number of terms in the geometric progression given first two and the last term?

Comment: you need $|a_2/a_1|\neq 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2$ be the first two terms and let $a_f$ be the final term, then the number of terms is $\log_{|a_2/a_1|}(|a_f/a_1|)+1$.